# c# Перевод hex UTF8 числа из массива байт в int напрямую

Tags: c#, .net-5

Есть массив байт `0xBB 0xBC 0xBD 0x31 0x43 0x43 0x68 0x00` представляющий из себя текст в UTF8 > `»јЅ1CCh`
Здесь `1СС` это значение которое мне нужно извлечь (0x1CC)
Возможно ли в C# это сделать напрямую не переводя байты в строку, а затем строку в значение?
Другими словами быстрее чем этот способ:

```
Uint.TryParse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes[4..^2]),out uint value) ? value : null; // C# 9.0
```

Comment: А известна ли вам позиция искомого числа в массиве?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.text.utf8parser.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Buffers_Text_Utf8Parser_TryParse_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Byte__System_UInt32__System_Int32__System_Char_ — это?

Comment: А как вы попали в такую ситуацию, что вам неизвестно место начала нужных вам данных?

Comment: Я так понимаю, вас производительность интересует. Вот это видели: [Hardware SIMD parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66371621/5045688)?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov воткнул туда свой ответ. Ставьте лайки :) Надо конкурс выиграть.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В .NET 5* есть класс [`Utf8Parser`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.text.utf8parser.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Buffers_Text_Utf8Parser_TryParse_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Byte__System_UInt32__System_Int32__System_Char_), который по идее делает то, что вам надо. Но вы должны указать ему позицию сами (выбирая нужный `Span`):

```cs
var bytes = new byte[] { 0xBB, 0xBC, 0xBD, 0x31, 0x43, 0x43, 0x68, 0x00 };
var numberBytes = bytes.AsSpan()[3..];
if (Utf8Parser.TryParse(numberBytes, out uint v, out int _, 'x'))
    Console.WriteLine($"{v:X}");
```

Проверка: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rh8FhQ

Обратите внимание, что можно указать только начальный байт, парсер прочитает столько, сколько сможет.

---

*а также в .NET Core 2.1+